# Hibernate Criteria. Construct with inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I have super class `AuditEntity`.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditEntityListener.class)
public abstract class AuditEntity {
    public static final String ID = "id";
    public static final String ORGANIZATION = "organization";
    public static final String CREATED_BY = "createdBy";
    public static final String MODIFIED_BY = "modifiedBy";
    public static final String CREATED_DATETIME = "createdDatetime";
    public static final String MODIFIED_DATETIME = "modifiedDatetime";
    public static final String STATE = "state";

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id")
    protected Organization organization;

    @Column(name = "created_datetime")
    protected Instant createdDatetime;

    @Column(name = "modified_datetime")
    protected Instant modifiedDatetime;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_by")
    protected User createdBy;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "modified_by")
    protected User modifiedBy;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "state")
    protected State state;

}
```

And entity extends the superclass.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"}, callSuper = false)
@Entity
@Table(name = "inventory_request")
public class InventoryRequest extends AuditEntity {

    public static final String NAME = "name";
    public static final String REQUESTER = "requester";
    public static final String SOURCE = "source";
    public static final String EVENT = "event";
    public static final String TRANSFER = "transfers";
    public static final String ASSIGNMENT = "assignment";
    public static final String INVENTORY_REQUEST_STATUS = "status";
    public static final String NOTES = "notes";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "inventory_request_id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "requester_id")
    private User requester;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "source_id")
    @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
    private User source;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false, length = 24)
    private InventoryRequestStatus status;

    @Column(name = "carrier")
    private String carrier;

    @Column(name = "tracking_number")
    private String trackingNumber;

    @Column(name = "note", length = 1024)
    private String note;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id")
    private Event event;

    @Column(name = "number", nullable = false)
    private Long number;

    @Column(name = "tracking_enabled", nullable = false)
    private Boolean trackingEnabled;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = Transfer.INVENTORY_REQUEST)
    private Set<Transfer> transfers;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = InventoryRequestAssignment.INVENTORY_REQUEST)
    private Set<InventoryRequestAssignment> assignment;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = InventoryRequestNote.INVENTORY_REQUEST)
    private Set<InventoryRequestNote> notes;
}
```

This is a class i want to select with criteria api.

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class InventoryRequestDTO extends InventoryRequest {

    public InventoryRequestDTO(InventoryRequest inventoryRequest,
                               Long completeSetsQuantity,
                               Long specificProductQuantity) {
        super(inventoryRequest.getId(),
                inventoryRequest.getName(),
                inventoryRequest.getEmail(),
                inventoryRequest.getRequester(),
                inventoryRequest.getSource(),
                inventoryRequest.getStatus(),
                inventoryRequest.getCarrier(),
                inventoryRequest.getTrackingNumber(),
                inventoryRequest.getNote(),
                inventoryRequest.getEvent(),
                inventoryRequest.getNumber(),
                inventoryRequest.getTrackingEnabled(),
                inventoryRequest.getTransfers(),
                inventoryRequest.getAssignment(),
                inventoryRequest.getNotes());
        this.completeSetsQuantity = completeSetsQuantity;
        this.specificProductQuantity = specificProductQuantity;
    }

    private Long completeSetsQuantity;
    private Long specificProductQuantity;
}
```

And this is method i tried to do that.

```
   @Transactional
    public Page<? extends InventoryRequest> getInventoryRequestPage(InventoryRequestSearchParams searchParams, Pageable pageable) {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<InventoryRequest> query = builder.createQuery(InventoryRequest.class);
        Root<InventoryRequest> root = query.from(InventoryRequest.class);
        Join<InventoryRequest, InventoryRequestAssignment> assignmentJoin = root.join(InventoryRequest.ASSIGNMENT, JoinType.LEFT);
        Expression<Long> specificProductQuantity = builder.count(builder.selectCase()
                .when(assignmentJoin.get(InventoryRequestAssignment.CATALOG).isNotNull(), 1)
                .otherwise(0));
        Expression<Long> completeSetsQuantity = builder.count(builder.selectCase()
                .when(assignmentJoin.get(InventoryRequestAssignment.CATALOG).isNull(), 1)
                .otherwise(0));

        Predicate predicate = InventoryRequestSpecificationComposer.builder()
                .searchParams(searchParams)
                .build()
                .compose()
                .toPredicate(root, query, builder);

        query.select(
                builder.construct(InventoryRequestDTO.class,
                        root,
                        completeSetsQuantity,
                        specificProductQuantity))
                .where(predicate);

        Query q = entityManager.createQuery(query);

        int totalRows = q.getResultList().size();
        q.setFirstResult(pageable.getPageNumber() * pageable.getPageSize());
        q.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());
        return new PageImpl<>(q.getResultList(), pageable, totalRows);
    }
```

But i get this exception.

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=generatedAlias2,role=com.connectsx.core.model.entity.InventoryRequest.createdBy,tableName=users,tableAlias=user2_,origin=inventory_request inventoryr0_,columns={inventoryr0_.created_by ,className=com.connectsx.core.model.entity.User}}]
```

Also I've got specification builder for audit entity, which fetches `organization`, `created_by`, `modified_by` properties. But if i select `InventoryRequest.class`, it works fine, and with DTO it fails.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in using a constructor expression if you pass the whole entity. You could just as well fetch the entity and call the constructor on the result list objects. However, if you really want a performance improvement, this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model. Since the attribute name is used as default mapping, you mostly don't need explicit mappings as 80% of the use cases is to have DTOs that are a subset of the entity model.

A sample model for your use case could look like the following:

```
@EntityView(InventoryRequest.class)
public interface InventoryRequestDTO {
    @IdMapping
    UUID getId();
    String getName();
    String getEmail();
    UserDTO getRequester();
    UserDTO getSource();
    InventoryRequestStatus getStatus();
    String getCarrier();
    String getTrackingNumber();
    String getNote();
    EventIdView getEvent();
    Long getNumber();
    Boolean getTrackingEnabled();
    @Mapping(fetch = FetchStrategy.MULTISET)
    Set<TransferDTO> getTransfers();
    @Mapping(fetch = FetchStrategy.MULTISET)
    Set<InventoryRequestAssignmentDTO> getAssignment();
    @Mapping(fetch = FetchStrategy.MULTISET)
    Set<InventoryRequestNoteDTO> getNotes();
    @Mapping("COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE assignment.catalog IS NULL)")
    Long getCompleteSetsQuantity();
    @Mapping("COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE assignment.catalog IS NOT NULL)")
    Long getSpecificProductQuantity();
}

@EntityView(User.class)
public interface UserDTO {
    @IdMapping
    UUID getId();
    // Other fields you need
}

@EntityView(Transfer.class)
public interface TransferDTO {
    @IdMapping
    UUID getId();
    // Other fields you need
}

@EntityView(InventoryRequestAssignment.class)
public interface InventoryRequestAssignmentDTO {
    @IdMapping
    UUID getId();
    // Other fields you need
}

@EntityView(InventoryRequestNote.class)
public interface InventoryRequestNoteDTO {
    @IdMapping
    UUID getId();
    // Other fields you need
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`InventoryRequestDTO dto = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, InventoryRequestDTO.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features i.e. have a repository similar to the following

```
@Repository
public interface InventoryRepository {
    Page<InventoryRequestDTO> findAll(Specification specification, Pageable pageable);
}
```

It will only fetch what you tell it to. Enjoy!